# ffmpeg - splitting TS file into shorter file by time

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a very long .ts video file - into a much shorter mp4 file.

The command I am using is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\230316.ts" -ss 00:05:08 -t 00:00:50 -c copy "C:\Users\Rob\Desktop\VideoSplitter\16.18.mp4"
```

However, when running this, ffmpeg gets "stuck" and repeats the same line over and over in the terminal:

```
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:50.01 bitrate=  76.8kbits/
```

When I press CTRL+C to exit, I notice the new file has been created... however, only with audio and no video at all.

Any ideas how to fix this please? I am using the latest ffmpeg.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You're using slow seek (`ss` placed after `-i filename`). In this case, ffmpeg decodes all frames till it reaches the in point. Assuming your file is at least as long as the inpoint value, you'll have to wait till it reaches that point. Alternatively, you can place `ss` before `-i` and do a fast seek. This should start the process much faster.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't fixed the problem. It still gets to a certain frame and gets "stuck":

frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     471kB time=00:00:49.93 bitrate=  77.2kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     471kB time=00:00:49.93 bitrate=  77.2kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     471kB time=00:00:49.93 bitrate=  77.2kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     471kB time=00:00:49.93 bitrate=  77.2kbits/
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     471kB time=00:00:49.93 bitrate=  77.2kbits/

Comment: Run the command with `-report` added and link to the *full* report.